# Glibc link difference causing segmentation fault

Tags: c, linux, gcc, linker, glibc

Something about the server I build on is broken (I am not the only one who uses it...). It is SLES 11 (no SP). I have tried uninstalling and reinstalling gcc, glibc etc with no success.

The problem is my built program seg-faults as soon as it hits a library function such as memset or strlen (note it is the calling of this function and not the function itself, the parameters are fine). I think it is definitely linking wrong and I can prove it is different to how it was with readelf. eg:

```
# readelf -s myprog | grep memset
  247: 081461d0    52 <OS specific>: 10 GLOBAL DEFAULT   27 memset@GLIBC_2.0 (3)
  3530: 081461d0    52 <OS specific>: 10 GLOBAL DEFAULT   27 memset@@GLIBC_2.0
```

vs a previous working version that says:

```
  69: 00000000     0 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT  UND memset@GLIBC_2.0 (2)
  2035: 00000000     0 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT  UND memset@@GLIBC_2.0
```

Its a fairly standard makefile and nothing has changed. The linker flags are:

```
LDFLAGS = -L$(companylibrarypath) -lourcompanylibrary -L$(mysql_lib_path) -lmysqlclient -L/usr/tls/ -lpthread -pthread -lz -L$(curl_lib_path) -lcurl -lxslt
```

Comment: Try rebuilding from scratch, could be old object files...

Comment: I have tried that. Also created new program with just printf and memset, memset has same problem...

Comment: @user3194963 How certain are you that it's not a bug in that program, even if it's a very simple one ? (I.e. Show us the that test program, the whole lot of it).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your programs by some bad way redefines functions like memset (instead of using the std library provided versions). It is likely caused by some headers, which may be "standard"... Also may be your compiler (gcc?) by some way generates (elf) code not for your platform...
Also you say the link process is failing, did you mean the linker is failing and cannot produce an executable?

Comment: Well, you are right about GCC.. someone had put a SLES 11 SP2 DVD in the drive and mounted it as a repository. Any attempt to re-install the development tools left it in this broken state.

Answer (score 0):

The functions you say fail (memset, printf) are extensively used, if your glibc was really that broken you wouldn't ever reach a shell when booting. And definitely you would't be able to compile anything.  I'd first look at the libraries it is picking up via the `-L...` flags. Check if a `LD_PRELOAD=...` snuck in somehow. See what `ldd` and `nm` tell you. Perhaps a `strace myprog 2> /tmp/log` or running it under a debugger clear up the mistery...

Comment: Well printf doesn't fail (different library?), and I'm saying the **link** process of any build I try is failing rather than glibc itself. I'd tried the rest (and valgrind too), but the elfread output looks most relevant. Also you can't follow it far enough in gdb even at assembly language level...